# How to insert this data to mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

```
Array
(
    [id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1
        )

    [kind] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [qty] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123
            [1] => 456
            [2] => 789
        )

)
```

This is how my data look like.Here is my insert 1 row code

```
function insert($table, $array_data)
{
    $key = array();
    $value = array();
    foreach($array_data as $v=>$row){
        $key[] = $v;
        $value[] = "'".$row."'";
    }
    $data_key = implode(',', $key);
    $data_value = implode(',', $value);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$table."(".$data_key.") VALUES (".$data_value.")";
    $this->setQuery($sql);
    $this->query();
}
```

Please help me make a function to insert multi rows somethings like

```
function insert_multi($table, $array_data)
{
    ...

    $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$table."(".$data_key.") VALUES (".$data_value1."), (".$data_value2.")";
    $this->setQuery($sql);
    $this->query();
}
```

I'm trying many ways but only return empty value or "Array" string. My point is make those value turn into this 
`INSERT INTO table (id, kind, qty) VALUES (1, v2, v3), (1, v2.1, v3.1),...`
Many thanks! ^^

Comment: If you all ready know how to build the queries I'd recommend looking at [multi_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

Comment: @Epodax that would be completely unnecessary. You can insert multiple rows into a table with a **single** query, which OP is suggesting...

Comment: The "Array" is returned when the "$data_value = implode(',', $value);" find an array. For example when the $value is the 'kind' or 'qty' value. You have to think how do you want to store this datas in db, maybe in json format or else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess you want something like this:

```
function insert_multi($table, $array_data)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $table . " (" . implode(',', array_keys($array_data)) . ") VALUES ";
    $rows = [];
    $columns = array_keys($array_data);
    for ($ii = 0; $ii < count($array_data[$columns[0]]); $ii++) {
        $values = [];
        foreach ($columns as $column) {
            $values [] = $array_data[$column][$ii];
        }
        $rows [] = "('" . implode("','", $values) . "')";
    }
    $sql .= implode(',', $rows);

    $this->setQuery($sql);
    $this->query();
}
```

but brace yourself for SQL injections when building queries that way...

Comment: It return `VALUES (1,1,1), (1,2,3), (123,456,789)` but i want it to be `VALUES (1,1,123), (1,2,456), (1,3,789)`.

Comment: Sorry, now it has been fixed

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you. Not tested so make changes if there is any syntax error.
you need to just generate a string like (val1,val2),(val3,val3)

```
function them($table, $array_data)
{

    ...
    $keys = array_keys($array_data);
    $length = count($array_data[$keys[0]]);
    $sql = '';
    for ($i=0;$i < $length;$i++)
    {
        $sql .= "('";
        foreach($keys as $index => $key){
           $sql .= $array_data[$key][$i];
           if($index < count($keys)-1)
             $sql .= ",";
        }
        $sql .= "')";
        // if there is another array member, add a comma
        if( $i < $length-1 )
        {
            $sql .= ",";
        }
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$table."(".implode(',',$keys).") VALUES ".$sql;
    $this->setQuery($sql);
    $this->query();
}
```

Comment: This get exactly the values that i want it to be, but the table keys is emtpy :(

Comment: Well you were already preparing keys for it. So $data_key from your question. even you can use $keys from my answer for your columns.